# "Dynamic" shifter in priority queue implemented on FPGA (SystemVerilog)

Tags: fpga, system-verilog

I'm implementing a priority queue on FPGA such that if some external signal is up (\$w_r\$) the priorities are evaluated and the priority queue us updated accordingly. The schematic is the following:

[image]

My approach is:

```
module priorityQueue(
input logic [13:0] dataIn,
input logic clk,
input logic wr,
output logic [7:0] out1,
output logic [7:0] out2
);

logic [13:0] dataInQueue [7:0];
logic [7:0] we;
bit [2:0] trigger = 0;



always_comb begin

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
    we[i] = (dataInQueue[i][13:8] < dataIn[13:8]);

if (we[7])
    trigger = 7;
else if (we[6])
    trigger = 6;
else if (we[5])
    trigger = 5;
else if (we[4])
    trigger = 4;
else if (we[3])
    trigger = 3;
else if (we[2])
    trigger = 2;
else if (we[1])
    trigger = 1;
else if (we[0])
    trigger = 0;  
end

always_ff @ (posedge clk)
    if (wr) begin
       dataInQueue[trigger] <= dataIn;
       case(trigger)
        3'b111: begin for (int i = 6; i < 0; i--)
                    dataInQueue[i] <= dataInQueue[i + 1];
                    end
        3'b110: begin for (int i = 5; i < 0; i--)
                      dataInQueue[i] <= dataInQueue[i + 1];
                      end
        3'b101: begin for (int i = 4; i < 0; i--)
                      dataInQueue[i] <= dataInQueue[i + 1];
                      end
        3'b100: begin for (int i = 3; i < 0; i--)
                      dataInQueue[i] <= dataInQueue[i + 1];
                      end
        3'b011: begin for (int i = 2; i < 0; i--)
                      dataInQueue[i] <= dataInQueue[i + 1];
                      end
         3'b010: begin for (int i = 1; i < 0; i--)
                      dataInQueue[i] <= dataInQueue[i + 1];
                      end
         3'b001: dataInQueue[0] <= dataInQueue[1];

        endcase
   out1 <= dataInQueue[7][7:0];
   out2 <= dataInQueue[6][7:0];

    end



endmodule
```

I'd like to focus on the always_ff part. Note that there a shift occurs depending on which \$w_e\$ was triggered. So, the shift depends on that factor. So far it seems to work, but is there a better to way to approach this in order to avoid redundancy?

note: the two "outs" are used only to visualize the queue in LEDS in the target.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely verify how the synthesis tool implements this that but here is my attempt at reducing the line number count:

```
always_ff @ (posedge clk)
if (wr) begin
   dataInQueue[trigger] <= dataIn;
   for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) begin
      if (trigger > i) begin
         dataInQueue[i] <= dataInQueue[i + 1];
       end
    end
end
```